# Issue with constraints on bottom layout

Tags: ios, layout, constraints

I'm getting some issues with a constraint relative from the bottom layout.
There are some views inside a UITabBarViewController. When I change to another view from the tab and return to first one, the viewcontroller not recognize the bottom layout as the tab bar, but from the bottom of the view.

I uploaded the problem here: https://sites.google.com/site/rveducationapps/layoutError.png?attredirects=0&d=1

I already tried put in ViewDidAppear and also ViewWillAppear:

```
[self.view layoutSubviews];
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

I logged the subviews in the two cases, the right one and after I exit and return to the view:

```
subviews:(
"<UIView: 0x146b2260; frame = (210 0; 814 712); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b22c0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x146a9eb0; frame = (727 672; 287 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x146aa070>>",
"<UITableView: 0x151d3400; frame = (0 0; 210 761); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x146b14b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x146ade20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>",
"<_UILayoutGuide: 0x146b23b0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b24a0>>",
"<_UILayoutGuide: 0x146b28a0; frame = (0 712; 0 56); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b2910>>"
```

)

```
subviews:(
"<UIView: 0x146b2260; frame = (210 0; 814 768); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b22c0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x146a9eb0; frame = (727 728; 287 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x146aa070>>",
"<UITableView: 0x151d3400; frame = (0 0; 210 817); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x146b14b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x146ade20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>",
"<_UILayoutGuide: 0x146b23b0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b24a0>>",
"<_UILayoutGuide: 0x146b28a0; frame = (0 768; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b2910>>"
```

)

I see there are some differences, specially in:`"<_UILayoutGuide: 0x146b28a0; frame = (0 712; 0 56); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146b2910>>"`

But I don't know how to fix it.

EDITED:
I think I fixed. I selected the UIViewController in the Storyboard and disabled the EXTEND EDGES->Under Bottom Bars option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are transitioning from your `UITabBarViewController` to a new `UIViewController`, and then attempting to go back to your `tabBarController` from that `UIViewController`, then you could simply **segue** back to the `UITabBarViewController`(The segue will take you back to your *rootViewController* for your `UITabBarViewController`).

If you need to transition back to a specific tab, instantiate a *custom* **segue** and send it back to a different tab using a different *specified VC*, this can be set in your `UITabBarViewController` class or in your applications `AppDelegate.m` file.